# error with passing my object with serializable?

Tags: java, android, class, exception, serializable

i was trying to send my object class GastronomyElement to another activity but i have got this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable   encountered IOException writing serializable    object (name =    com.example.despegarteproject.classes.GastronomyElement)
```

i have seen another posts like this but i couldn not solve it. this is my class code

```
 public class GastronomyElement implements Serializable {

    String id, name, formattedAddress, formattedPhoneNumber,  reference, photo;
    List<String> photos;
    Boolean openNow;
    Horarios horarios;
    List<Review> reviews;
    String priceLevel;
    double  latitude, longitude;
    Double rating;

    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId () {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFormattedAddress () {
        return formattedAddress;
    }

    public void setFormattedAddress (String formattedAddress) {
        this.formattedAddress = formattedAddress;
    }

    public String getReference () {
        return reference;
    }

    public void setReference (String reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    public String getPhoto () {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto (String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public List<String> getPhotos () {
        return photos;
    }

    public void setPhotos (List<String> photos) {
        this.photos = photos;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude (double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude (double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Double getRating () {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating (Double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public Boolean getOpenNow () {
        return openNow;
    }

    public void setOpenNow (Boolean openNow) {
        this.openNow = openNow;
    }

    public Horarios getHorarios () {
        return horarios;
    }

    public void setHorarios (Horarios horarios) {
        this.horarios = horarios;
    }

    public String getPriceLevel () {
        return priceLevel;
    }

    public void setPriceLevel (String priceLevel) {
        this.priceLevel = priceLevel;
    }

    public String getFormattedPhoneNumber () {
        return formattedPhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setFormattedPhoneNumber (String formattedPhoneNumber) {
        this.formattedPhoneNumber = formattedPhoneNumber;
    }

    public List<Review> getReviews () {
        return reviews;
    }

    public void setReviews (List<Review> reviews) {
        this.reviews = reviews;
    }

    }
```

and this is how i am sending it

```
Intent act = new Intent (context, ActivityLugarDetalles.class);
act.putExtra("elementDetails", elementDetails);
startActivity(act);
```

i would appreciate your help! thank you!

Comment: are classes Horarios and Review serializable as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `GastronomyElement` contains objects of type `Horarios` and `Review`, those classes (and any fields they contain, recursively) must also implement `Serializable`. The exception is probably because one of these classes (or some data contained in one of those classes) fails to implement `Serializable`. (The other fields of `GastronomyElement` all implement `Serializable` already.)